# acceptcallback replacement on AsyncCallback

Tags: c#

I'm following the example on a site http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463947/Working-with-Sockets-in-Csharp in order to build a socket program.

I was just wondering what is the replacement for acceptcallback under the following code.

```
Socket sListener;

SocketPermission sPermission = new SocketPermission(NetworkAccess.Accept,
       TransportType.Tcp, "", SocketPermission.AllPorts);

sListener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry("");
IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint ipEndP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 4510);

sListener.Bind(ipEndP);

sListener.Listen(10);

//error below this
AsyncCallback aCallback = new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback);           
sListener.BeginAccept(aCallback, sListener);
....
```

I search the net and tried the following but nothing seems to work:

```
AsyncCallback aCallback = new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback);           

AsyncCallback aCallback = new AsyncCallback(sListener.AcceptCallback);

AsyncCallback aCallback = new AsyncCallback(this.AcceptCallback);

AsyncCallback aCallback = new AsyncCallback(this.IAsyncResult);   

AsyncCallback aCallback = new AsyncCallback(aCallback);      

AsyncCallback aCallback = new AsyncCallback(sListener.aCallback);

AsyncCallback aCallback = new AsyncCallback(this.aCallback);
```

another reference i was looking at was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722270/c-sharp-server-does-not-trigger-acceptcallback

This is my first time doing sockets in C#.

Comment: Isn't there an "AcceptCallback" in the example you're copying from? It's a user-defined method. You have to define one of your own.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AcceptCallback is a method you create and that gets called when the asynchronous operation completes.

Look at the example found at:

http://[msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.asynccallback.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.asynccallback.aspx)

```
// Create the delegate that will process the results of the  
            // asynchronous request.
            AsyncCallback callBack = new AsyncCallback(ProcessDnsInformation);

// The following method is called when each asynchronous operation completes. 
        static void ProcessDnsInformation(IAsyncResult result)
        { ...
```